# bun:go: how to change `belongs-to` relation mapping field in bun

Tags: go, go-pg

I am working on bun that has an execting database in PostgreSQL. There was a relationship between the two tables. `Order` and `ResPartner` where `Order` table has a foreign key of `ResPartner` table having column name `contact_partner`

```golang
type Order struct {
    bun.BaseModel    `bun:"select:sb_order"`
    ID               int64       `bun:"id"`
    GenOid           string      `bun:"gen_oid"`
    ContactPartner   *ResPartner `bun:"rel:belongs-to"`
    ContactPartnerID int64       `bun:"contact_partner"`
}
```

```golang
type ResPartner struct {
    bun.BaseModel `bun:"select:sb_partner"`
    ID            int64  `bun:"id"`
    Name          string `bun:"name"`
}
```

I try to make queries like this.

```golang
err = db.NewSelect().Model(&order).
        Relation("ContactPartner").
        Scan(ctx)
```

But it is giving error.

`reflect: call of reflect.Value.Field on ptr Value`

I think bun try to find a field name like `contact_partner_id`. Is there any way to override the field name?

UPDATE: I have updated my question. see this repo for example: [go-db-test](https://github.com/milon19/go-db-test)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share your database schema.

Comment: Can you provide more context for your code? like, how the `db`, `ctx`, `host` and `order` variables are defined? I've tried a variation of your code on my side and it appears to be working

Comment: In the below repo I uploaded a similar database and an example code. Please have a look.
https://github.com/milon19/go-db-test

Answer (score 4):

You can map relationships in a bun:go something like:

belongs-to:

```
 type User struct {
      ID        int64 `bun:",pk"`
      Name      string
      ProfileID int64
      Profile   *Profile `bun:"rel:belongs-to,join:profile_id=id"`
    }
```

has-one:

```
type User struct {
    ID      int64 `bun:",pk"`
    Name    string
    Profile *Profile `bun:"rel:has-one,join:id=user_id"`
}
```